# Consider the system $x'=-y-x^2$, $y'=x.$ Find a reversor $S$, identify Fix$(S)$ and show that the origin is a nonlinear center.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, linearization

Can I please have help solving the following? I am not quite sure how to approach this problem and was wondering if someone could please help. Thanks!

Consider the system $$x'=-y-x^2$$ $$y'=x.$$ Find a reversible $S$, identify Fix$(S)$ and show that the origin is a nonlinear center.

Comment: What is a "reversor"?

Comment: Typo error fixed. I mean reversible @RobertLewis

Comment: I'm still a little confused.  Is your system called "S"?   do you want to find a reversed version of $S$, where the trajectories flow in the opposite direction?  And to find the fixed point(s) of $S$?

Comment: @RobertLewis yes, you are correct. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Well, you have made things pretty clear at this point.  Thanks.  Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system $S$ given by

$\dot x = -y - x^2, \tag 1$

$\dot y = x, \tag 2$

has precisely one fixed point, $(0, 0)$, since

$0 = -y - x^2, \tag 3$

$0 = x, \tag 4$

has exactly the one solution

$x = y = 0. \tag 5$

The Jacobean matrix $J_S(x, y)$ of $S$ is

$J_S(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial \dot x}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \dot x}{\partial y}\\
\dfrac{\partial \dot y}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \dot y}{\partial y} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -2x & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 6$

thus

$J_S(0, 0) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 7$

the characteristic polynomial of this matrix is

$\lambda^2 + 1 = \det(J_S(0, 0) - \lambda I) = \det \left (\begin{bmatrix} -\lambda & -1 \\ 1 & -\lambda \end{bmatrix} \right ), \tag 8$

and so the eigenvalues of $J_S(0, 0)$, which are the roots of this polynomial, are

$\lambda = \pm i; \tag 9$

since the eigenvalues are purely imaginary, the point $(0, 0)$ is classified as a *center* of the system $S$.

To reverse the system $S$, that is, to write the equations for a system $S_R$ the trajectories of which run opposite to those of $S$, we merely need to negate both $\dot x$ and $\dot y$; thus the equations of $S_R$ are

$\dot x = y + x^2, \tag{10}$

$\dot y = -x; \tag{11}$

the analysis of $S_R$ parallels that of $S$; the principal fact of import is that we have

$J_{S_R}(0, 0) = -J_S(0, 0) =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \tag{12}$

with the same characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2 + 1$, and hence the same eigenvalues $\pm i$ as given in (9).  Thus $S_R$ is also possessed of a center at the origin.

Comment: Thank you for delineating step by step your derivation. It is clear and nicely done, Robert.

Comment: @rudinsimons12:  you are most welcome my friend, and thanks for the "acceptance".  Cheers.

Comment: @rudinsimons12 For nonlinear systems, the equilibrium at $0$ is called a center if all trajectories in some punctured neighborhood of $0$ are closed curves enclosing $0$. You cannot conclude that $0$ is a center for $S$ by just considering the linearized system $S_l$. The point of the question is to invoke the theorem that says that a center of $S_l$ remains a center for $S$ if it's a symmetric equilibrium for $S$ (which is where the fixed set of a reversor comes in).

Comment: @Maxim:  curioius. I am familiar with a different definition of center.  Meanwhile, can you give me a link to the theorem you cited?  Thanks.

Comment: Perko, *Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems* gives the definition of a center and a simplified version of the theorem (for systems symmetric wrt one of the axes, which is sufficient here). Do you have a reference for a different definition of a center of a nonlinear system? If $S$ is analytic, a center of $S_l$ may become a center or a stable or unstable focus of $S$ (also defined geometrically). It seems to defeat the purpose to still call it a center of $S$ in the latter case.

Comment: Thank you @Maxim I am reading Perko right now

Comment: @Maxim:  and I will check it out as well.  And thanks to you for pointing this out as well.  By the way, can you give the chapter/section in Perko where I might find this?